# program crashes when inserting new items to vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<Flight> flights;
while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
    flights.push_back(*(new Flight()));
// read some info...
}
```

after the second loop the program crashes with the message:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x776315de in cpi.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2."

How can I solve the problem?

edit:

```
vector<Flight> flights;
while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
    flights.push_back(Flight());
// read some info...
}
```

i tried this and still crash on the second loop

edit: full while

```
    int count = 0;
    myReadFile >> output;
    while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
        flights.push_back(Flight());
        flights[count].setFlightNum(atoi(output));

        myReadFile >> output;
        int x = atoi(output);
        flights[count].setStartX(x);
        myReadFile >> output;
        int y = atoi(output);
        flights[count].setStartY(y);

        count++;
        myReadFile >> output;
    }
```

Comment: can you show us the constructors (default and copy) of `Flight`?

Comment: its an empty constructor - all the members are ints or floats.  no copy constructor

Comment: is this a live project? just friendly concern for our friends in the sky.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the `while` loop?

Comment: @user1027958: then I really doubt whether it is crashing while inserting elements into vector, looks like crash is there somewhere else in the while loop.

Comment: @user1027958, the corruption may be occurring elsewhere. If you post the full `while` loop someone may spot the problem.

Comment: Can you add declaration of `output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stream directly into ints. If you have to read "tokens" then use a std::string but reading into a char array is always dangerous.

You should also probably have code that will create a Flight object from a stream, albeit that I dislike the use of `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Flight& )`, I find it "intrusive" and non-extensible. I prefer factories for this. However let's write that function anyway:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Flight& flight )
{
    int flightnum, x, y;
    if( is >> flightnum >> x >> y )
    {
       flight.setFlightNum( flightnum );
       flight.setStartX( x );
       flight.setStartY( y );
    }
    return is;
}
```

And now:

```
std::vector< Flight > vec;

while( myReadFile )
{
    Flight flight;
    if( myReadFile >> flight )
       vec.push_back( flight );
}
```

Comment: almost, your code allows half-flights to be read silently, and fails for the last flight.  'while(myReadFile>>FlightNum>>StartX>>StartY) ...

Comment: i have no idea what is the difference from my code but it works now. thanks

Comment: Yes, you could just do that. I'd prefer to stream into the object outside of the loop but I could have used 3 ints and done one if test. I might half create a Flight but then the streaming would still fail and it wouldn't get added to the vector.

Comment: I have modified the streaming function so as not to touch the object unless it is going to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
vector<Flight> flights;
while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
  flights.push_back(Flight());
  // read some info...
}
```